# Why can't install 15MB app when I have 180MB free?

Tags: insufficient-memory

I want to install an app from Google Play, where it's said it has 14.99MB.

However, when I click on `Install`, it says "Insufficient storage".

When I click `View Storage`, there says 180MB available.

Why can't I just download it to the SD Card?

As I see, this has been a persistent error, though in other posts people are talking about 15 MB of free space. I got more than 10 times that, so isn't it strange?

Also, the `Storage` screen don't show the available space as part of the bar "Device Memory", above. Does that happens with anyone else?

I'm using a Sony Xperia.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look into our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), most of your questions are already answered there. And no, it's never 15MB free – it's at least 25MB free and more likely 10% (don't blame me, I didn't make that rule).

Comment: Thanks. What I meant is that, in the other posts I saw, people were complaining for having far less free memory than I have, and they couldn't install a small app (< 1MB in their case).

Comment: Yes, I know. This issue is asked about here almost once a day. See the "Related" section next to your question for examples, or click the `insufficient-memory` tag below your question (364 posts – and not all questions about this issue used this tag, so it's definitely more).

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo). Mention the exact name of Android model and Android version.

Comment: Diskinfo: 875KB on my device. Device memory available: 194MB. SD Card: 7.96GB available. It says there's no room to install Diskinfo! Android sucks, that's all! Android version is 4.4.2. What do you mean with Android model? Don't you actually mean the device model? It's a Sony Xperia E1 D2104.